# Android device using a lower API target style than it should

Tags: android, adb, android-styles, backwards-compatibility

My android device, the Pixel XL, while using for debugging purposes in the Android Debug Bridge, seems to be using my app's styles-v21 XML instead of the regular styles XML.

The Android version on my device is 8.1 (API Level 27), so why is it using the lower API level style instead of the other? Am I misunderstanding that devices 21 and below are supposed to use the styles-v21 and everything else should use the regular styles.xml?

My project's Compile SDK Version and Target SDK Version is 27: Android 8.1 (Oreo). Min SDK Version is 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I misunderstanding that devices 21 and below are supposed to use the styles-v21 and everything else should use the regular styles.xml?

Yes.

Assuming you mean that you have both `values/styles.xml` and `values-v21/styles.xml`, then the "v21" version will be used on any device that is v21 ***or newer***, not v21 or older.

Comment: Thank you! So if that's the case, should I be making values/styles-v for each major API level below my target version? Or would it seem to be the best case to just remove the "styles.xml" and solely use the styles-v21.xml if I am not adding anything "new" in terms of the API level past 21?

Comment: @akinoreiki that sort of question is hard to answer without knowing exactly what you're trying to do. In general, you want to put the "base" styles in `res/values/` and then put "new" styles (using `android:elevation`, say) in `res/values-v21/`. In my own experience, I don't wind up using these special-case styles too often; 95+% of what I do just goes in `res/values/`.

Comment: I think I have been having problems with my themes the entire time because I misunderstood that the styles.xml is for previous versions and the v21 is for 21+ API level. With that, I should be able to fix my issues. Using AppCompat theme values as my "higher level" API themes I think was causing the confusion since I was mixed up. Not sure my explanation makes sense, but you helped solve my problem, either way. Thank you.